# How do you change the video category in Rumble?

Tags: rumble

For some reason, the video category dropdownlist was buggy, and I couldnt choose any other category than Sports, so I saved it that way and thought I'd edit it later. But, when I go to edit the video, the option to change the category doesnt appear, just changing the description, title, tags, etc.

Is there a way to change the  video category in Rumble?